# DirectoryServicesCOMException was unhandled Invalid DN syntax in Directory service

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I tried to connect to our AD using LDAP Query through c# .

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldap.mysite.gov.sa:389/ou=mysiteCSP,ou=Government CA,o=National Center ,c=LA"); 
// de.RefreshCache();
DirectorySearcher dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);
dsearch.Filter = "(cn=aabs@mysite.gov.sa)"; //Search how you want.  Google "LDAP Filter" for more.
SearchResultCollection rc = dsearch.FindAll();
X509Certificate stt = new X509Certificate();
```

and i get this error :-

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147016654
  Message=An invalid dn syntax has been specified.

  Source=System.DirectoryServices
  ErrorCode=-2147016654
  ExtendedError=13
  ExtendedErrorMessage=Invalid DN syntax
  StackTrace:
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll()
       at NCDCToolkit.Utilities.LDAPQuery.query(String csp_name, String query) in c:\Users\yrajhi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NCDCToolkit\NCDCToolkit\Utilities\LDAPQuery.cs:line 23
       at NCDCToolkit.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\yrajhi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NCDCToolkit\NCDCToolkit\Program.cs:line 46
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

`ou=mysiteCSP,ou=Government CA,o=National Center ,c=LA`

^^ This is not a valid DN. Look at the `distinguishedName` property of your Organisational Unit in Active Directory for the correct name.

They should be in the format `ou=myou,dc=mydomain,dc=local` or similar.

Comment: Actually it is valid, perhaps minus the trailing space on National Center.